# Which function is a faster alternative to FOR? Google Apps Script - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have a code :

```
function check(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = sh.getSheetByName("1")
  var getNames = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues().filter(String).toString().split(",");
    for (var j = 0; j < getNames.length; j++) {
      var sheetnow = sh.getSheetByName(getNames[j]);
      var last = sh.getSheetByName(getNames[j]).getLastRow();
      for (var i = 1 ; i <= last ; i++ ) {
        var rangeactive = sheetnow.getRange(i ,7).getValue();
        var setval = sheetnow.getRange(i ,8);
          if (rangeactive == 1 && setval.getValue() == "") {
              setval.setValue("OK");
          }   
      }
    }
}
```

It still works fine, but For will be very slow because all the sheets have more than 200000 rows and will run more than 6 minutes. Is there any other more efficient way? Thanks

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13p4xrIfACk_l_oRgBnDr8VaOtEL9o4SxeIql5eqryOc/edit#gid=1480346296

Comment: Using getValues() and setValues() is faster than using multiple getValue() or setValue() calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function check(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("1")
  const names = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  names.forEach(n => {
    let s = ss.getSheetByName(n);
    let vs = s.getRange(1,7,s.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
    let sv = s.getRange(1,8,sh.getlastRow()).getValues();
    vs.forEach((r,i) => {
      if(r[0] == 1 && r[1] == '') {
        sv[i][0] = "OK";
      }
    });
    s.getRange(1,8,sv.length,sv[0].length).setValues(sv);
  });  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Cooper, it's faster indeed. But in the end it gives an error and doesn't end the script, why is that? ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null```  line 5,7

Comment: I don't know I don't have your data so I can't really debug it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow links to offsite resources.  If it's not in the question then I don't use it.  The best I can do is give you a faster approach and let you debug it.

Comment: sorry, I just added it to the question section.

Comment: Yes but I still don't follow links to offsite resources..